# Yum claims library is installed but it is not

Tags: yum, qt

I'm trying to compile a program using cmake which has a dependency on libQtWebKit_debug.so. According to *yum provides*, that library is supposed to be in */usr/lib64/* but it is not there:

```
yum provides */libQtWebKit_debug.so

Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
1:qt-devel-4.8.5-10.fc20.i686 : Development files for the Qt toolkit
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libQtWebKit_debug.so



1:qt-devel-4.8.5-10.fc20.x86_64 : Development files for the Qt toolkit
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libQtWebKit_debug.so
```

Reinstalling the corresponding package (*qt-devel*) did not help either: *yum remove qt-devel*, followed by *yum install qt-devel*.

Comment: what does `locate libQtWebKit_debug.so` return?

Comment: How are you determining it's not there? What's the output of your `whatprovides` command? Can you `ls` the file?

Comment: locate libQtWebKit_debug.so gives no results, the same for ls.

Comment: Could you update the post with the commands you used and their output? How did you re-install the package?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. There seems to be some change which dropped file `/usr/lib64/libQtWebKit_debug.so` from package `qt-devel` sometime after version qt-devel-4.8.6-**13**.fc21.x86_64 (<- have that file) vs. qt-devel-4.8.6-**18**.fc21.x86_64 (<- do not have that file).

Looking into changelog [Bug 1168259 - qt-devel contains some webkit components which probably were not meant to be included](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1168259) seems to be the cause:

```
# rpm -q qt-devel --changelog | head -n 16
* Wed Nov 26 2014 Rex Dieter <rdieter@fedoraproject.org> 1:4.8.6-18
- omit previously-overlooked webkit bits (#1168259)

* Sun Nov 09 2014 Rex Dieter <rdieter@fedoraproject.org> 1:4.8.6-17
- Broken qmake_qt4 in /usr/lib/rpm/macros.d/macros.qt4 (#1161927)

* Mon Nov 03 2014 Rex Dieter <rdieter@fedoraproject.org> 1:4.8.6-16
- macros.qt4: standalone, improved %qmake_qt4 macro (sync'd with qt5 version)

* Sat Nov 01 2014 Kevin Kofler <Kevin@tigcc.ticalc.org> - 1:4.8.6-15
- sync system-clucene patch from qt5-qttools (some QDir::mkpath in QtCLucene)

* Sun Oct 26 2014 Kevin Kofler <Kevin@tigcc.ticalc.org> - 1:4.8.6-14
- build against the system clucene09-core (same patch as for qt5-qttools)

* Tue Sep 16 2014 Rex Dieter <rdieter@fedoraproject.org> - 1:4.8.6-13
```

So I would ask in the bugreport or mention this fact to the author of the software you are trying to compile.